# How so I install Syndesis on OpenShift when I don't have cluster:admin rights. Is this even possilble?

Tags: syndesis

I've build Syndesis from source on my local machine and I now want to deploy it to a remote OpenShift in a shiny new namespace.

I've tried:

```
$ syndesis install -p kurt --local

ERROR: No CRD Syndesis installed or not enough permissions to read them. Please run --setup and/or --grant as cluster-admin. See 'syndesis install --help' for more information.

$ install --setup --grant developer

Installing Syndesis CRD
ERROR: Cannot install CRD 'Syndesis'. You have to be a cluster admin to do this.
```

I don't have cluster:admin.

Can it be done w/o having cluster:admin rights?

Answer (score 2):

It should be, for the most part, by using the `oc` commands from the [Minishift installation guide](https://syndesis.io/quickstart/#vanilla-minishift). The most part, i.e. when this fails, is with the permissions needed to run Camel K or use Knative, if those haven't been setup by the cluster administrator the `oc new-app` will error out at the end with permission issues, though the bits to run Syndesis without Camel K or Knative should be installed and setup.

I think there's an ongoing effort to replace all installation methods with the Syndesis operator, installing Operator Lifecycle Manager and setting it up by the cluster administrator should make this friction-less for non cluster administrator users.